# getting below screen while scrolling down/up with pagingEnabled props in FlatList. I want to achieve full screen vertical slider

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I would like to achieve the behaviour of full screen vertical slider. I have added `pagingEnable` prop to `FlatList` but its not working properly.

Below is my code.

please see this image as a reference : [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z1-0jDDZ5rqBvbqMcw2XytHVUhROkG2o/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUaa8.gif)

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, FlatList, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

const VerticalSlider = () => {
  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: item,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          height: height,
        }}>
        <Text style={{color: '#FFF', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 30}}>
          {index}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      pagingEnabled
      data={['red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink']}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
      bounces={false}
    />
  );
};

export default VerticalSlider;
```

Comment: i tried your code, it's working for me, no white space on top like in screenshot you shared.  are you using react-navigation? did you share exact code snippet that you're trying?

Comment: @LakshmanKambam thanks for your reply, im using the exact same code which i have posted here , im checking in android phone, im my case the view with red background color is also showing in view with green background color and view with green background color is  showing in screen with blue background color

Comment: can you cross check this one again becuase i can't see any gap above screen view - https://snack.expo.io/@klakshman318/04de86

Comment: Strange its working fine in the expo simulator, but when im running it on my phone its not running as its running in that simulator

Comment: yes exactly, that's what i've been trying to explain.. may be device compatibility issue?

Comment: How can i solve this issue, any idea?

Comment: if i can reproduce your issue i could've fixed it but i can't. share device name and model in which you're getting this issue.

Comment: im getting issue in realme 5 pro